# Need help merging two seperate strings together

Tags: python

It print the list how I want it but I want them next to each other on the same line instead of on different lines.
The inputs that I am using are abcdefghi and jklmnopqr

```
str1 = (input("please enter a string: "))
str2 = (input("please enter a string: "))

for i in range(0, len(str1)):
  e = str1[i] + str2[i]
  print(e)
```

I want it to print something like: ajbkclemdnfogphqir

but it prints it like this:

```
aj

bk

cl

em

dn

fo

gp

hq

ir
```

Comment: `print` will add a `newline` character unless you tell it to add something else: `print(e, end='')`

Comment: Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

```
str1 = (input("please enter a string: "))
str2 = (input("please enter a string: "))

e = ' '
for i in range(0, len(str1)):
  e = e + str1[i] + str2[i]
print(e)
```

Hope it will be helpfull